# Aligning recordings of two cameras with different parameters

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I'm working on object recognition from recordings of two cameras – RGB and thermal. This project has two separate cameras (in one unit) that record the same area.
I will run my neural network on those recordings. I need to align the recordings so that the neural network knows where the overlap between those two recordings is to get the most from the training.
The cameras have different FOVs, resolutions, and aspect ratios, but I know those parameters from the manufacturer's site.

My first idea was to try OpenCV's templates and Canny Edge Detector and try to map it, but that was before I learned the cameras' parameters.
Source: [medium article](https://medium.com/@aswinvb/how-to-perform-thermal-to-visible-image-registration-c18a34894866)
This approach could be modified with Hough Transform, which is used, for example, [here](https://github.com/cloudxlab/opencv-intro/blob/master/hough_transforms_lane_detection.ipynb), but I do not think that there will be a significant improvement.

To illustrate this problem further, here is my initial solution, which does not usually perform well.

**Thermal input:**

[image: Thermal image]

**Cutout:**

[image: Cutout in RGB image]

Right now, I'm probably looking for a solution with intrinsic and extrinsic matrixes as I think that will be the best approach, but I do not know where to start, and I appreciate any tips. I found one [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/camera-calibration-with-example-in-python-5147e945cdeb) that mentions this, but I think I'm a few parameters short of calculating the matrix.

From the manufacturer, I have the parameters and some more, but I think that those are all needed (I don't have the FOV, though):
RGB camera:

- Focal Length: 6 ~ 180mm
- Effective Resolution: 1920(H)×1080(V)
- The Angle of View: H: 59° ~ 2.4 (What is V? not specified, I guess)

Thermal:

- Focal Length: 100mm (can be set)
- Resolution Sensor is 640×512. The image can be scaled up to 704×576
- The Angle of View: H: 6.2° V: 4.9

I probably need to create a matrix that can then be applied to the camera to display the smaller viewport of the camera in the bigger one, but I don't know where to start. Could you nudge me in some direction?

I have tried homography matrixes with SURF, SIFT and RANSAC, but sadly, I had no luck as usually the points are not found correctly due to very different recordings.
I used [OpenCV official tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html), which did not find any points and this [tutorial from pythonpool](https://www.pythonpool.com/cv2-findhomography/), which did the result below.

I also find this [research](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.14833v1.pdf) which could help me, but it is a little harder to implement.

[image: Homography match]

Original images:
[image: Orignal RGB image]
[image: Orignal thermal image]

Comment: As the two cameras are fixed in one unit you can [calibrate](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) each of them with the same chessboard pattern. Besides you can search the net for information on stereo calibration. If you need more help please share some code that you have tried and describe a specific problem.

Comment: @Markus I cannot calibrate the cameras with a chessboard for multiple reasons. The thermal camera doesn't see it the same way as a regular camera, the cameras will need to be calibrated multiple times, and I cannot start the calibration that easily. I've linked a paper that comments on this topic without calibration, and I think it is possible with the matrices. 
I can link the code, but it won't be much different from the tutorials and examples. I need to figure out the matrix and to process which can do this.

Comment: @Blank If you have physical access to your cameras, the easiest solution is most likely to use the chessboard pattern with a hot incandescent light bulb. The black regions of the chessboard will absorb the heat more than the white regions, creating a chessboard pattern in both visible and thermal spectra, allowing you to use the builtin calibrate functions in opencv. If your cameras are deployed "in the field" and it is hard to physically access them you are in a much tougher spot.

Comment: @mCoding Yeah, they are "in the field", and I really cannot use the chessboard since it would be tough to calibrate it that way. It would be easier to manually do it for two kinds of cameras and then "set it and forget it". However, I wanted to do it at least with the intrinsic and extrinsic matrixes, which would help me build the solution more robustly or with another approach.

Comment: Here I see two different questions: 1) how can I estimate intrinsic/estrinsic parameters of my system without the ability of doing a proper calibration? 2) Can I use an image registration technique (SIFT, RANSAC, etc) to find the an appropriate transform that aligns the two images? As it is the question is very broad and difficult to answer. Maybe better focus on just one of the two questions and go into deeper detail.

Comment: @StefanoM Sadly, in the process of answering the question, I thought about a lot of possible solutions. The calibration using the image registration technique did not prove to be working, so I had to try to use the intrinsic/extrinsic matrixes. This whole post is written as a statement of all possible solutions I tried so other people could easily see what is good or not. I'm still working on the matrixes.

Comment: From the example images, I see no reason why a simple 2D homography on the images would not suffice - such as the one you would compute by a couple of point correspondences. The objects seem to be rather far away from the cameras compared to the distance between the camera centers. If all your images have this property, you might get away with this assumption P0=H*P1 quite well...

Comment: @AndréAichert It does not work because there are almost no points found automatically, and there are just loads of false positives, making the warp impossible.

Comment: options 1) FInd a couple good images and just lick on points 2) use checkerboard as suggested multiple times and use those points to compute just the homography and potentially lens distortions. 3) If you say the points are so hard to detect, use a video sequence of a single light (e.g. flash light) that you move. For the latter two cases note that distance to the camera centers matters. So try to be far away.